# Is it possible to combine two tr commands into one?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, tr

I have the following two commands:

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < file1.txt > file2.txt
tr -s "[:punct:]" " " < file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Is it possible to combine them into a single command? My following attempt did not work:

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -s "[:punct:]" " " < file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Comment: When use redirection with piping the command, an **input redirection** should be applied to the **first command** in the pipe, and an *output* redirection - to the *last command*: `tr ... < file1.txt | tr -s ... > file2.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the input redirection before the first `tr`, not the second one.

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < file1.txt | tr -s "[:punct:]" " " > file2.txt
```

Otherwise, the first `tr` tries to read from the terminal instead of the file, and the second `tr` reads from the file instead of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

`tr` does not allow run multiple operations on a single command line invocation. You would be forking two processes of `tr` in a pipeline to be able to achieve what you wanted to do. But if you can use `sed` (GNU version) you can do it in a single operation

```
sed 's/\([A-Z]*\)/\L\1/;s/\([[:punct:]]*\)//g' file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **combine the two commands by only using the last one** (since output of the first is discarded anyway - both commands reading and writing from/to the same files).